# mysql duplicate record field

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1062

Is there a way to overwrite or skip duplicate records?

## 1062 - Duplicate entry '2' for key 1

is there a way to add : insert on duplicate key update to a sql file that only has insert?

Comment: Insufficient input - More information needed to provide answer.

Comment: more importantly why would you want a duplicate key?  a key identifies a single record in a table...

Comment: I need to change it to insert on duplicate key update the sql insert file but not sure how

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [12.2.5.1. INSERT ... SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html) and [12.2.5. INSERT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html)

And look for

> Specify IGNORE to ignore rows that
>   would cause duplicate-key violations.

Answer (score 0):

try [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

```
INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```

Although usually people forget to put the autoincrement field for the id and thus the error.

Comment: can I just stick that anywhere near the top?

Comment: yes you can. read the docs anyway for a complete description on usage